# fetch data from api but the id comes with Hyphen -

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

so what i'm trying to do is get live prices between crypto coins it was going smoothly until some id came with dash and the problem appear

[image]

here is the code

```
var btcbnb, ethbnb, usdtbnb, usdcbnb, ltcbnb;
  var btcln, ethcln, usdtcln, usdccln, ltcln, bnbln ,bch;
  var liveprice11 = {
    "async": true,
    "scroosDomain": true,
    "url": "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum%2Cusd%2Clitecoin%2Cbinancecoin%2Cbinance-peg-bitcoin-cash&vs_currencies=bnb%2Clink%2Cusd",
  
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
  }
  
  $.ajax(liveprice11).done(function (response){
    btcbnb = response.bitcoin.bnb;
    ethbnb = response.ethereum.bnb;
    usdtbnb = response.ethereum.bnb;
    usdcbnb = response.usd.bnb;
    ltcbnb = response.usd.bnb;
    // link
    btcln = response.bitcoin.link;
    ethcln = response.ethereum.link;
    usdtcln = response.usd.link;
    usdccln = response.usd.link;
    ltcln = response.litecoin.link;
    bnbln = response.binancecoin.link;
    bch = response.binance-peg-bitcoin-cash.usd;
    console.log(bch);
  });
```

this is the line that has the problem

```
 bch = response.binance-peg-bitcoin-cash.usd;
```

really hope someone can help ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, JS doesn't let you access object members by name that have a dash like that.

A simple workaround would be

```
bch = response['binance-peg-bitcoin-cash'].usd;
```